# I want to trigger Azure datafactory pipeline whenever there is a change in Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-logic-apps

I have a datafactory pipeline that converts SQL database table into csv file. Now I want to trigger the pipeline whenever there is a change in the azure SQL database. How can i achieve that using azure logic app or some other trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two triggers for **SQL DB** that are very straight forward ...

[image: SQL DB Triggers]