# Build trriger set on fire when an event occurs to the input dataset in azure data factory

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory, ssms-2017

i want to build a trigger in ADF that set on fire when an event occurs to the input dataset , i used linked service to import the input dataset from SQL server management studio.

I tried to create a storage event trigger, but it doesn't seem to be working. The trigger requires a connection to Azure Blob and the specification of a Blob path that ends with or starts with certain values. However, I only have an input dataset that is linked to a SQL Server. Can you help me troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the trigger to fire when a change occurs on your source data (SQL server)? For example, when a new row is inserted into a table?

Comment: yes,the trigger will fire when a change occurs on the source data (sql server)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at the moment there is no trigger type in ADF to fire on change in source data. You will need to create a scheduling trigger to run every X minutes (or hours\days...), and in the first step of the pipeline you run to check for the condition. Then use an IF activity to continue the process if the condition is met.
Another option is to use logic app, please see this answer with an example: [Azure Data Factory SQL trigger events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563667/azure-data-factory-sql-trigger-events)